# Don't let me take the last bit

Tags: reference-request, behavioral-economics, experimental-economics

I believe everyone has experienced something like the following once in her or his life :

- There is a cake on the table and three people to share it.
- The three people each eat a quarter of the cake.
- They wait.
- After some time, brave miss 1 eats another eighth.
- After some more time, bold mister 2 cuts another 16th and eats it.
- Then miss 3 cuts another 32th and eats it.
- etc.

Is this kind of behavior where people do not want to grab the last part of the pie (i.e., social endowment) documented in experimental economics?

Comment: You might find this related question over on cogsci interesting. http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/8182

Comment: I can't find any direct evidence of the behavior you are asking about in experimental economics. However, one place to look for related behavior is in common-pool resource games. Is there evidence that players avoid being the one to completely exhaust a resource even though they were happy to deplete it?